# Input value equal with previous enter value

Tags: php

let's say that I have a form

```
<form > 
<div class="control-group"> 
   <label class="control-label" for="numeinculpat">Nume inculpat</label> 
   <div class="controls"> 
     <input type="text" id="numeinculpat" placeholder="Nume inculpat" name="nume" /> 
   </div> 
 </div>
<div class="control-group"> 
   <label class="control-label" for="numeinculpat2">Nume inculpat2</label> 
   <div class="controls"> 
     <input type="text" id="numeinculpat2" placeholder="Nume inculpat2" name="nume" /> 
   </div> 
 </div> 

 </form>
```

---

And the user introduce some empty value .
How cand can I do if someone enter wrong data(or empty),when enter again, the input to have the value of data that he previous introduced ??

Answer (score 0):

Add a `value` attribute and get last value from `$_POST` like below

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="numeinculpat2" 
    placeholder="Nume inculpat2" 
    value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['nume']) ? $_POST['nume'] : '' ); ?>" 
    name="nume" 
/>
```

Input name must be unique, don't use same `nume` for other input, This might help

Comment: But on submit the page will refresh and the post will be empty,no?

Comment: if you are submitting it to same page `<form action="" method="post">` then it will contain last values. It best practice to submit on same page

Comment: If you're submitting to a different php than the form, the $_POST will be empty. You should use session routine (session_start() and $_SESSION) to store the $_POST data before redirecting them back to the form.

Comment: it's on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `action` and the `method` attribute of `form`.

Follow the basic tutorial from here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting it to the same page use " method="post">. Now when you submit and if the value is blank or whatever is the problem you will get the last entered value also use this to get the value.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])
{
 $text1=$_POST["numeinculpat"];
}
```

over your html input

```
<div class="control-group"> 
   <label class="control-label" for="numeinculpat">Nume inculpat</label> 
   <div class="controls"> 
     <input type="text" id="numeinculpat" placeholder="Nume inculpat" name="nume" value="<?php echo $text1 ?>" /> 
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Now when you submit the value you will get the last entered value.